# Take any 8 3-digit numbers $\in\mathbb Z^+$.There will always be at least two of them which you can put next to each other to form a 6-digit number …

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Take any 8 3-digit numbers $\in \mathbb Z^+$. There will always be at least two of them which you can put next to each other to form a 6-digit number which is divisible by 7. Why?

Comment: Have you tried the pigeonhole principle? That's what it usually is.

Comment: Do you know the divisibility rule by $7$ using modified sums of digits?

Comment: Hint: $\ {\rm mod}\ 7\!:\ n = a+1000b \equiv a-b\equiv 0\iff a\equiv b.\,$ We have $8$ numbers and $7$ remainders mod $7,\,$ so at least two  have the same remainder, by pigeonhole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 6 digit number can be represented as $1000y+x$ where $y$ and $x$ are 3 digit numbers.

Now note that: $$1000y+x\equiv 6y+x\mod(7)$$

You can always choose two numbers with same remainder using the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: I understand the second part with the pigeonhole principle.
But how do I prove that 2 3-digit numbers with the same remainder put together to form a 6-digit one is always divisible by 7?
Thanks for your help

Comment: @user176791 $\exists x,y$ that are two different numbers of your 8 3-digit numbers and that satisfy $x\equiv y\pmod{7}$ (by the pigeonhole principle). Then $1000y+x\equiv 6y+x\equiv 6y+y\equiv 7y\equiv 0\pmod{7}$.

Answer (score 0):

a) Show that a 6-digit number, which is formed by two 3-digit numbers that leave the same remainder with respect to division by $7$, is divisible by $7$.

b) Think about how you can use a) to conclude.